# How to validate array item types with networknt/json-schema-validator?

Tags: java, json-schema-validator, light-4j

its probably a very simple thing that Im missing, but my json-schema-validator ([networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator)) doesnt validate the type of my items inside an array.

This Java-snippet should yield errors:

```
var schema = "{\n" +
                    "  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#\",\n" +
                    "  \"type\": \"array\",\n" +
                    "  \"items\": [\n" +
                    "    {\n" +
                    "      \"type\": \"integer\"\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "  ]\n" +
                    "}";

var input = "[true,false,{},\"foo\"]";

var factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V202012);
var jSchema = factory.getSchema(schema);
var errors = jSchema.validate(new ObjectMapper().readTree(input));
System.out.println("Errors: '"+errors.stream().map(ValidationMessage::getMessage).collect(joining(", ")) +"'");
```

but 'errors is empty. Over on [www.jsonschemavalidator.net](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) this is invalid as expected.

What obvious am I overlooking here ?

Thanks!

Comment: So the solution is to downgrade the schema-version .. "items" has a new name in version "2020-12" and its not implemented yet. With "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema" and "VersionFlag.V7" it starts working.

See https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/issues/633

Comment: the array <items> in the version 2020-12 are named <prefixItems> and are working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
    JsonSchemaFactory jsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V202012);

    SchemaValidatorsConfig schemaValidatorsConfig = new SchemaValidatorsConfig ();

    //schemaValidatorsConfig.setFailFast(true);
    schemaValidatorsConfig.setHandleNullableField(true);
    schemaValidatorsConfig.setTypeLoose(false);

    //build json schema node
    JsonNode schemaNode;
    try {
        schemaNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(schema);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
    
    //build input json node
    JsonNode jsonNode;
    try {
        jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        
    }
    
    //validate the json with the schema
    Set<ValidationMessage> validationErrors;
    
    JsonSchema jsonSchema = jsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(schemaNode, schemaValidatorsConfig);
    
    validationErrors = jsonSchema.validate(jsonNode);
```